# How do I update a single record in react-query outside of mutation?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to use a function to update a cached react-query [following this example](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/QueryClient?from=reactQueryV3&original=https%3A%2F%2Ftanstack.com%2Fquery%2Fv3%2Fdocs%2Freference%2FQueryClient#queryclientsetquerydata) using a websocket message.

I was trying something like this:

```
useSubscription('/queue/..', message => {
        const id = JSON.parse(message.body).itemId;
        queryClient.setQueryData(['items', { id: id }], JSON.parse(message.body));
});
```

However, this has no effect at all on the cache and the specific item being updated. My expectation is a real-time update once the message is received. The original cache is built elsewhere using `useQuery()` as follows:

```
...
const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useQuery(['items'], fetchItems);
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't the QueryKeys array match what you are using in the `useQuery`?

So when calling `setQueryData` it should be called with the same key: `['items']` and not `['items', { id: id }]`

`['items', { id: id }]` is a different query than `['items']` so `['items']` will not be invalidated when you update data for `['items', { id: id }]`.

For an example, see https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys

```js
function useUpdateTitle() {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: updateTitle,
    onSuccess: (newTodo) => {
      // ✅ update the todo detail
      queryClient.setQueryData(['todos', 'detail', newTodo.id], newTodo)

      // ✅ update all the lists that contain this todo
      queryClient.setQueriesData(['todos', 'list'], (previous) =>
        previous.map((todo) => (todo.id === newTodo.id ? newtodo : todo))
      )
    },
  })
}
```